# RxJava get gps and fused location

Tags: android, geolocation, rx-java

I have two methods in my app to get user location. Both methods return Observable. First method gets gps Location via Location Manager. Second method gets Fused Location.

```
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public Observable<Location> getRxGpsLocation(boolean single)
    {
        PublishSubject<Location> subject = PublishSubject.create();

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,
                5, new LocationListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
                    {
                        subject.onNext(location);

                        if (single)
                        {
                            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                            subject.onComplete();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: Disableeedd");
                        if (single)
                        {
                            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                        }
                        subject.onError(new Throwable("Error nit found Location"));
                    }
                });

        return subject;
    }


    //I use this library to get Fused Location https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public Observable<Location> getRxFusedLocation()
    {
        RxLocation rxLocation = new RxLocation(AppClass.getApp());
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setNumUpdates(1)
                .setInterval(1000);

        return rxLocation.location().updates(locationRequest);
    }
```

So my goal is to make this chain of requests:

1. Request for Gps Location
2. If got Gps location, than return it
3. If in 15 seconds did not get gps location than cancel gps request and start fused location request

How can i combine this two methods in one with 15s timer after first request?

Comment: They do the same thing, it's just Fused automates a lot of stuff and more optimized for battery usage and stuff. I don't understand the use of both LocationManager and Fused.

Answer (score 0):

In short, for your question. You have to create a stream from LocationManager, and a stream from FusedLocationProviderClient
Then you apply a "timeout" operation. For example:

```
locationManagerObservable()
.timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 .onErrorResumeNext { error -> 
        if(error is TimeoutException)
            fusedLocationObservable()
        else
            Observable.error(error)
    }
```

Use a Subject for your purpose is not a good option. You should research on how to create an Observable from callback API.

This is a [good article](https://medium.com/@mikenguyenvan/it-is-2020-i-still-write-a-topic-about-converting-android-callback-api-to-rxjava-stream-976874ebc4f0) guide you how to convert location provider sources to Rxjava stream
You can check the source code in the article [here](https://github.com/roscrazy/android-rx-location)